# Differentiable function only at $x=n$ where$ $n is an integer

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is only differentiable at integer points. Is this possible? If does, what kind of function is $f$?

Comment: If there are no other conditions on $f$, sure.

Comment: @AndréNicolas any examples..? I can't think of an example

Comment: For example, $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational; and $f(x) = \sin^2(\pi x)$ if $x$ rational.

Comment: @SimonS: Easier to describe than mine, I was using $\frac{1}{q^2}$ for non-integer rationals $p/q$, $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thnks Alot~

Comment: @SimonS Brilliant! Thnks Alot~

Comment: @user197137: You are welcome. We can in the same way get a function differentiable precisely at the integers, and $k$ tmes differentiable there. With more effort, one can get infinitely ifferentiable.